# Git Brag: How do I extract git data for my brag sheet?

Tags: git

Say I want to add a blurb to my resume like *"Recent coding experience: In the last # months I've written # lines of code including # lines of ruby, # lines of javascript, # lines of css, and # lines of specs."* What's a good way to extract such stats from git?

(Since nobody should be impressed by code quantity without evidence of quality, assume such evidence is elsewhere.)

To simplify, forget about merging results from multiple repos. Also, count only lines in HEAD and ignore deleted or overwritten lines.

How do I squeeze these numbers from git?

Comment: So... you wan't to brag about the amount of code you are able to come up with, but need help coming up with the code (git commands) to extract the data. Anyone spotting a contradiction there?

Comment: @sehe, If you want to hire a programmer who already has all the answers, and never has to ask questions to learn more, then you don't want me.

Comment: excellent retort. Perhaps I wouldn't have felt the need to post my surprised response if you had shown what you had googled/proof-of-concepted by yourself. Right now this question is only inches from a '_just give me the codez_' question. You even go as far as to 'allow us' to `forget about merging results` (sic). The only reason I didn't vote to close/downvote is because the comments _do show_ you have at least thought about the question and I do trust _would_ be come up with something if needed. The meta-topic for this question: It's all about communication again :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --author foo --*stat
```

There are a number of stat commands.  --stat --numstat --shortstat --dirstat.  Some provide the information you want.  You can accumulate the stats, figure out the file type by directory or file name, or actual file inspection, and output as necessary.

However, as someone who interviews people, I'm pretty sure I would find that statistic entirely useless and a sign of bad thinking on the applicant's part.

Comment: I've hired programmers too, and it's one thing to know that the applicant can write good code, and another to know he can do it _productively_, day after day. Seems that these stats would help with that. Why is that a sign of bad thinking?

Comment: @Mori: Autogenerated code, copy-pasted code, can all inflate numbers. I'd rather have someone who refactored something into a library than dumping ten slightly different versions of the same code in somewhere. A five day task involving one character being added, deleted, or changed might be a sign of a very productive person. Now, someone who could say they wrote a significant fraction of a major project…that would be something different. I still probably wouldn't care about the line count.

Comment: @Mori: [smart and get's things done](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/05.html). That isn't bad thinking. Now, write it already and [get shipping](http://www.amazon.com/Linchpin-Are-Indispensable-Seth-Godin/dp/1591843162/). Also, a [google search does wonders](http://tinyurl.com/3ry243e) as ever ([link](https://gist.github.com/234560))

Comment: Managing by numbers. The worst thing you can do when it comes to software.